# Can I use jwt tokens with Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, jwt

I've developed few Spring Boot applications with jwt tokens, Angular 7 and MySQL. Now I would like to move to Firebase for authentication ONLY. A few tutorials show that we can implement Firebase directly through Angular. I'm confused: do I need to generate jwt tokens in Spring Boot when I use Firebase or does Firebase provides jwt token? If yes, how can I authorize a user through Firebase?

I read few items of Firebase documentation, still I'm not clear. I couldn't find any reference regarding my question. What approach can I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to generate jwt tokens in Spring Boot when I use Firebase or Firebase provides jwt token?

No. Firebase auth is entirely done client-side when using the provided SDKs from Firebase.

However, if you need to do some special auth, such as integrating with LDAP/AD or some other enterprise shenanigans, then you would need to do [custom token creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/#custom_token_creation) that client-side SDKs would use to authenticate the user. This is the only time where Spring Boot would come into play where it generates a custom token for your Angular to use.

Please see the following answer linked below on how to integrate the Firebase admin SDK to verify users from your Angular app: [How to use Firebase with Spring boot REST Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183107/how-to-use-firebase-with-spring-boot-rest-application)

Comment: Thank you so much, This does authentication and return UID. But how to protect endpoints using authorization?