# Firebase authentication in Vaadin Flow

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm new to Vaadin Flow and I'm trying to port an android application, in which Firebase is used as the only authentication provider. My (dumb) problem is that I can't find any resource or binding to Firebase API. Have some of you succeeded in using Firebase auth in a flow project ?

Answer (score 1):

I created this example application couple of weeks ago. It user Firebase Authentication and it's JavaScript library to do authentication. Then the JWT token is sent to the Vaadin Flow server, validated and stored so that it can be used to detect who the active user is.

https://github.com/mstahv/vaadin-firebase-auth-example

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring for security, or your own solution?

If you're using a custom solution, maybe the reply in this thread is of use
[Firebase user authentication for java application (Not Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824660/firebase-user-authentication-for-java-application-not-android)

The token can be saved in the session and used as you wish.

Here's a question that might be relevant if you're using Spring boot
[How to use Firebase with Spring boot REST Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183107/how-to-use-firebase-with-spring-boot-rest-application)

Comment: I'm trying to use my own solution as I didn't find any Spring security binding to Firebase. The REST API does not allow user registration, which exist in the android app, and the admin SDK doesn't permit client login. The only thing left is the javascript SDK which I'm trying (failing) to use inside the vaadin project.